# Combining Video Editor Scenes in One Scene

Tags: video-sequence-editor, scene

I am trying to create an animatic in blenders Video Sequence Editor and I have found a tutorial by a Mathieu Auvray on the Project Gooseberry youtube page where he shows a feature where you can import different VSE scenes into one scene.

However, when I followed his tutorial, I noticed that a few things he clicked on that weren't in any of the versions of Blender I could find.

Here was Mathieu's screen:
[image: Mathieu's VSE screen]

Here is mine in all my blenders:
[image]

Is there a plug in I am missing, or a setting I haven't turned on?
I have been googling it for a while and have been coming up empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gooseberry project uses a development branch of blender that has some modifications that haven't been applied to the main blender development yet. This is one change that is currently only in the gooseberry branch.

You can compare the code for the relevant panel in [gooseberry branch](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/gooseberry/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_sequencer.py;4925b5c9a9a81377a2bbe5467ccd378702ef67bb$793) and the [master branch](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/space_sequencer.py;c55cf743cdc68f4c1aeabba91d98a0bec96a62ef$791) to spot the change. There are also other supporting code changes elsewhere to get that to work, see [this commit](https://developer.blender.org/rBb8e88c1821478fd93c5f625812da85b0c23d6dce).

There are gooseberry builds available to download from [blender daily builds](https://builder.blender.org/download/) or you can look at [building your own version of blender](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender).